# Trouble with getting data from nodejs/express because of CORS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

**Solution here:** [Trouble with getting data from nodejs/express because of CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130255/trouble-with-getting-data-from-nodejs-express-because-of-cors#comment52152153_32130255)

So i have a problem with getting data from nodejs/express because of CORS.

I'm getting error something like this (sorry, error i translated with google):

> Query from an external source is blocked: one source of policy prohibits reading remote resource on http://localhost:8080/api/login. (Cause: Failed to query CORS).

I'm trying to send query with angular **$http.post**

```
$http.post($rootScope.api + 'login', {
    email: form.email.$viewValue,
    password: form.password.$viewValue
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.data);
});
```

Here is my server code (i cut some code, because i think it not important):

```
/* some nodejs requires */
var cors = require('express-cors');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/batarindashboard');

require('./config/passport')(passport);

/* some express settings */
app.use(cors({
    allowedOrigins: [
        'localhost:*', '127.0.0.1:*'
    ]
}));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Something is happening');
    next();
});

/* sign up api */

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    failureRedirect : '/api/passport_message',
    failureFlash : true
}), function(req, res) {
    res.json({
        'message': 'You successfully signed in!'
    });
});

/* passport_message api */

/* is_logged_in api */

/* logout api */

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

And passport file (maybe problem is here. Why not?)

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('./../app/models/user');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    /* some serialize deserialize code */

    /* sign up strategy */

    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    }, function(req, email, password, done) {
        User.findOne({
            'local.email':email
        }, function(err, user) {
            if(err) return done(err);

            if(!user) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'No user found.'));
            }

            if(!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));
            }

            return done(null, user);
        })
    }))
};
```

Comment: What is the value of `port` on the server side and what is the value of `$rootScope.api` on the client side?

Comment: @mscdex server side port 8080, rootScope.api = http://localhost:8080/api/

Comment: Where was the html for the page containing that client-side js served from? Did you go to `http://localhost:8080/` in your browser? If so, I don't see how it could be a cross-origin request ...

Comment: @mscdex nope, client side is on http://localhost:63342/BatarinDasboard/public/#/

Comment: Are you trying this with Chrome? If so, you can try starting Chrome temporarily with the `--disable-web-security` flag, since Chrome [does not support CORS requests from localhost by default](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743). Or try in Firefox?

Comment: Any reason your not using [this cors module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) ? express-cors maybe old / outdated.

Comment: @mscdex thank you! In chrome this is work! But if i try set false "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy" in firefox - i get the same error. In IE it works fine from the start :D